# Android. How to put combo box to the navigation menu

Tags: android

I write Android app. There is navigation menu in my app. I want to put there combo box. Is it possible? If yes, can you show me XML I should write? I searched all around but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it by myself. So..

Usually you have `DrawerLayout` in your activity. Something like this (here is `activity_main.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Usually, when you create new activity with navigation menu `nav_header_main.xml` looks so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then you just need to add your control to `nav_header_main`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:text="Android Studio"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconLang"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_language"
            android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_langs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconLang"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:entries="@array/languages_array" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

One more `LinearLayout` allows us to put `RelativeLayout` under the header. `RelativeLayout` includes necessary controls. Menu items are inflated under the `nav_header_main`. Ready!

[image]